What is the limit to the number of threads that can be spawned - and can it be increased?
I was under the impression that I could, in principle, do multi-threading with hundreds of threads simultaneously (regardless if it makes sense). But this code throws a std::system_error at memory location... when commenting in 16 "folders" (works still fine with 10) which corresponds to (only!) 16 threads:
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

void function_t(const std::string& folder) {
   std::cout << "Processing folder: " << folder << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   std::vector<std::string> folders{ 
      std::string("1"), 
      std::string("2"), 
      std::string("3"), 
      std::string("4"), 
      std::string("5"), 
      std::string("6"), 
      std::string("7"), 
      std::string("8"), 
      std::string("9"), 
      std::string("10"),
//    std::string("11"), // Commenting in these lines throws an error. 
//    std::string("12"),
//    std::string("13"), 
//    std::string("14"), 
//    std::string("15"), 
//    std::string("16") 
   };

   std::vector<std::thread> threads{};

   for (const std::string& folder : folders) {
      threads.emplace_back(function_t, folder);
   }

   for (std::thread& thread : threads) {
      thread.join();
   }

   return 0;
}


Why is that so - and can I work around it? I'm on Windows / Visual Studio 22.
(The point is not if it MAKES SENSE to spawn 100 threads, I only try to understand where the principle limitation comes from.)

Maybe you can print out the system error message and see what it outputs.

Cannot reproduce, The output is garbled by using cout in parallel, but no error message appears.

No repro when I try to run your code, including the commented out part. I don't see anything inherently wrong.  The only thing that could go wrong would be if folders goes out of scope before the threads join. But that's certainly not the case.

What platform (operating system) are you on?  Windows? Mac?  Linux? Linux on Windows? Cygwin? Something else?

Strange!! Are you on gcc?  I'm on Windows / Visual Studio 22.

@Duke - I'm on Windows 11 + VS2022 as well.  A few things to check - make sure you got plenty of disk space and aren't low on virtual memory.  Minimize your PATH environment as well in case a rogue runtime is getting picked up. Or just statically link.
Reboot just to be sure. If that doesn't fix it, try to set a breakpoint where the error is thrown.

It doesn't seem to be a msvc limit

does it works with Clang for Windows (using the CRT AFAIK)? Does it works in Clang in WSL? I expect the CRT to be the source of the issue. If yes, it will fail for the first and not the second. AFAIK there is a limit of 64 somewhere in their implementation but clearly not something smaller (I never found any issue with only 16 threads so far).

I commonly run with ~200 threads using the same Microsoft CRT. And given that 16-core CPU's are common enough, a 10-thread limit would be insane.

@JérômeRichard: You might misremember the 64 core limit for Windows.

@MSalters Indeed, this one. A pretty small limit since modern server CPUs reach >=128 cores and >=256 threads both for AMD and Intel CPUs (with some of them released up to 7 years ago -- not to mention the Ampere Altra for ARM), though not related to the OP issue.

Without either an error message or a complete example, this really can't be answered. If function_t takes a gigabyte, this would be logical.

How many threads can a C++ application create and What is the maximum number of threads a process can have in windows

I copy-pasted your program, uncommented the extra entries, and it works fine on godbolt. (VS 17.0 is Visual Studio 2022.)


What is the limit to the number of threads that can be spawned - and can it be increased?

There are limits, as every thread consumes system resources (OS handles, memory for stack). I'm 99% sure C++ does not define the limits. It is rather platform specific. I remember the days when I experimented with threads and I created thousands of them.
See:

How many Windows handles in use is "too many"?
Pushing the Limits of Windows: Handles (Mark Russinovich)

Also take into account that the more threads you have, the more job is for the OS task scheduler.

But this code throws a std::system_error at memory location... when commenting in 16 "folders"

Most likely it is related to data race or buffer overrun. Try address sanitizer (ASAN).
